# How do you write a dot product with symbols in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I'm looking to dot two vectors or symbols in sympy so that the (latex) output is similar to what the code below would display, but with an actual sympy function e.g. RA.dot(RB)... How would I go about doing this?

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.interactive import printing
printing.init_printing(use_latex = True)

RA = Symbol('\mathbf{R}_A', commutative = False)
RB = Symbol('\mathbf{R}_B', commutative = False)
dt = Symbol('\cdot', commutative = False)

display(RA*dt*RB)

# I would prefer something like

display(RA.dot(RB))  # If RA and RB are type Vector, VectorAdd etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Use this:

```
A = MatrixSymbol('\mathbf{R}_A', 1, 1)
B = MatrixSymbol('\mathbf{R}_B', 1, 1)
dt = MatrixSymbol('\cdot',1,1)

A*dt*B
```

Or just:

```
A = MatrixSymbol('\mathbf{R}_A', 1, 1)
B = MatrixSymbol('\mathbf{R}_B', 1, 1)

A*B
```

Comment: Thank you. The second version doesn't output a dot product, but two bold symbols multiplied. The first option seems ok, but behaves badly when used as a denominator unlike standard vectors (e.g. looks like M^-1)

Comment: Your second bit of code does output a dot product if "pprint(A*B)" is used, and seemingly not if "display(A*B)" is used (for latex output)

Answer (score 0):

So a solution to the problem **for LaTeX output** is this:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.interactive import printing
printing.init_printing(use_latex = True)


A, B, dt = symbols('A B \cdot', commutative = False)
display(A*dt*B)
```

However, functions like simplify(), expand(), factor() do not work so well with non-commutative symbols so if you want to do any math I recommend the following code:

```
expr = A*dt*B

l = [i for i in expr.atoms()]
nl = [Symbol(str(i)) for i in l]

for i in range(len(l)):
    expr = expr.subs(l[i],nl[i])

### Perform your maths now that everything is commutative, then revert back to non-comm
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare it also for commutative symbols. Just make the dot a standalone non-commutative symbol and disable product simplification.

```
import sympy as sm
a,b,c= sm.symbols('a b c')
dt = sm.Symbol('\cdot ',commutative=False)
sm.Mul(a,dt,b,dt,c,evaluate=False)
```